# Rules of logarithm

Tags: logarithms

Can anyone help me figure out how to go from the first expression to the second?

$$
\begin{equation}
\ln D=u+\delta(e-p)+\gamma y-\sigma r
\end{equation}
$$

$$
\begin{equation}
\pi \ \ln (D/Y)= \pi[u+\delta(e-p)+(\gamma -1) y-\sigma r]
\end{equation}
$$
where $y=\ln(Y)$

$u,\delta,\gamma,\sigma=$ Constants

$e=$ Current exchange rate

$p=$ Current price level

$r=$ Domestic interest rate

$D=$ Demand

Comment: Is it given that $y=\ln(Y)$?

Comment: Please at least give clear explanation to every variable appeared in your expressions.

Comment: Yes $\ln (Y)=y$

Comment: $\ln(D/Y) = \ln D - \ln Y$.

Comment: Hint: $\ln(D/Y)=\ln(D)-\ln(Y)=\ln(D)-y$.

Answer (score 1):

First of you don't need that $\pi$ messing thins even more(*). 

So, you have: 
$$\ln D=u+\delta(e-p)+\gamma y-\sigma r$$
Since $\ln Y=y$,

 we can apply the rule of the logarithm: $$\ln(a/b)=lna-lnb$$
for $$b=Y$$ and $$a=u+\delta(e-p)+\gamma y-\sigma r$$

Then your equation simply follows.

(*)Note that:  $c\ln (a/b)=c(\ln a-\ln b )$ So for $c=\pi$ you got the desired expression.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with the second equation, divide both sides by $\pi$, then distribute the $y$ on the RHS.  On the LHS, use the fact that $\ln \left(\dfrac{D}{Y}\right) = \ln D - \ln Y$.  Since $y = \ln Y$, rewrite the LHS as $\ln D - y$.  Then add $y$ to both sides and you end up with the first equation.

To go from the first equation to the second, just work backwards:

1. Subtract $y$ from both sides in the first equation.
2. On the LHS, rewrite $y$ as $\ln Y$.
3. On the LHS, rewrite $\ln D - \ln Y$ as $\ln \left(\dfrac{D}{Y}\right)$.
4. On the RHS, rewrite $\gamma y -y$ as $(\gamma -1)y$.  (i.e., factor the $y$)
5. Multiply both sides by $\pi$.  Done!